# Se deberían de permitir las preguntas "¿Alguien ha logrado X?"

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

En particular me encontré con una pregunta de este tipo:

[Divi theme + woocommerce + mercadopago](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137160/divi-theme-woocommerce-mercadopago)

Si bien entiendo que todas las preguntas deberían de tener si no algo de esfuerzo por lo menos algo de investigación previa, no entiendo muy bien qué hacer en estos casos.

Mi primer instinto es proponer el cierre de la pregunta debido a que pregunta algo muy extenso, aunque pienso que podría cerrar la puerta a preguntas muy interesantes hechas por novatos como por dar un ejemplo "*¿Alguien ha configurado su compilador JVMCI con JDK 8 para usar la graalVM en Windows 10? Si es así ¿Cómo lo hicieron?*" (el cual es un tema real que creo que es muy difícil hallar en internet).

Comment: De acuerdo al [help], las preguntas deben realizarse de acuerdo a [ask], por lo tanto no son válidas este tipo de preguntas que comentas, estaría basada en opiniones no en algo concreto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Claro que no.

Creo que esta pregunta encaja con *cualquiera* de los motivos de cierre. La cerraría como *basada en opiniones*, pero el motivo en este caso no importa mucho, lo importante es votar para cerrarla. Y, la verdad, no le veo mucha discusión al tema: está bastante claro en [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

---

Al final de tu pregunta, me parece que lo estás comparando con un caso totalmente diferente, principalmente porque mencionás: `¿Cómo lo hicieron?` y `es muy difícil hallar en internet`. Esos son 2 puntos que aportan bastante más a una pregunta. Implican que estás teniendo un **problema puntual** que no es sencillo de resolver, y que **investigaste algo**, porque no estás encontrando la información. Y si bien idealmente le falta contenido a tu caso hipotético, perfectamente podría ser salvado con una buena edición.

Estos son sólo lineamientos muy generales que intentan ayudar a ver qué está dentro de la temática del sitio, pero no están escritos en granito. A fin de cuentas, todo se trata de **la propia experiencia de los profesionales en la comunidad**, para discernir el tipo de pregunta que se está haciendo. Perfectamente puede haber una pregunta de menos de 10 palabras, pero que trate sobre algo interesante para responder con código concreto, o una pared de texto que divague sobre opiniones... La primera es salvable con una buena edición.

Seamos coherentes, y veamos el trasfondo de lo que realmente se está preguntando, y del código que esa pregunta representa.

En el caso de la pregunta que enlazaste, *¡¿es complicado montar una tienda con un tema?!* -Vamos, ¿qué tiene eso que ver con la temática de SOes?

Pero no nos olvidemos un punto importantísimo: cuando se pone en espera a una pregunta, el principal objetivo es que el autor pueda editar la pregunta, guiándolo a una mejor respuesta, y para aclarar, por sobre todo, qué se está preguntando y qué se intentó hasta ahora. Esto no significa que la pregunta sea insalvable. Todo lo contrario, es la forma de decir que **queremos responder, pero aún no podemos**, o que sería realmente un lío de respuestas que apuntan a lados diferentes sin un objetivo concreto. Quizás el autor haya intentado algo y tenga un código en el que se le complicó la implementación de un tema en su tenda, y una buena edición haría que cambie una pregunta de opinión bastante ambigua y superflua en una buena pregunta.

Este fue el comentario que dejé en esa pregunta:

> Hola @JuanPablo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te comento que seguimos otro mecanismo en el sitio. Esperamos que muestres qué estás intentando, dónde estás teniendo problemas, qué problemas específicos, y recién ahí ver posibles respuestas concretas (no es un reemplazo de Google). Quizás te sea útil leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Si se te ocurre cómo modificar tu pregunta para seguir estos lineamientos, encontrarás el enlace a **editar** debajo de tu pregunta.

Comment: El usuario comentó que no ha hallado en internet, por eso me confundí, aparte de que desconozco del tema.

Comment: @Ruslan entiendo, y está genial que lleves la inquietud a Meta. Si fui efusivo, es porque así opino sobre las preguntas como la que enlazaste (tu pregunta acá en Meta está genial).

Comment: No olvidemos que las preguntas no se cierran al principio. Se ponen en espera. En espera de que el autor las mejore para que sean aceptables. Y en una pregunta puesta en espera **el motivo es muy importante**. Es la indicación que se da al autor original sobre lo que está mal y lo que debe mejorar.

Comment: Tenés toda la razón @Jose, y por lo general suelo dejar muy claro este punto en todas mis respuestas en Meta. Creo que la respondí algo apurado, y voy a editar para incluir tu punto.